# there is a wrong in my simple android calculator

Tags: android

Excuse me , I encode a simple android calculator,then it show XML wrong,I have change some code but it doesn't work.why like this?

this is the main code

```
<LinearLayout xmlsn:android ="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools ="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layou_width="fill_parent"
android:layou_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingTop="5dip">
<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="40dip"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
andorid:layout_marginRight="5dip"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:gravity="center_verticallright"
android:textColor="#ff0000"
android:textSize="30dip">
</TextView>
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="5dip">
```

then I get a error warning :

[image: the erro warning]

it's says

---

Multiple annotations found at this line:

- error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)
- Element type "LinearLayout" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" 
  or "/>".

thanks

Comment: u should paste the `xml`, the picture is not clear

Comment: @ jeet sorry image in my pc is very large

Comment: @Sieryuu now I have put the code on .I thought it large enough to see

Comment: because the picuture isn't clear so I get votedown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. Are you sure, you've closed your `LinearLayout` tag?
The editor cannot find the tag `</LinearLayout>`

It should probably be in the very bottom of your layout file.

Answer (score 0):

i think your textview doesnt have a closing > . Just above the `</textview>` add an >

your pictures are to small to really see it, so maybe you should just upload your code

Comment: I have </textview>,sorry about the picture ,I have put the main code on

Answer (score 0):

try to put

```
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

at the end of the `xml`

and the speeling is incorrect , should be `android:layout_height` not `android:layou_height`
same with the width

so the result will be

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="5dip"
    xmlsn:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        andorid:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center_verticallright"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:textSize="30dip" >
    </TextView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="5dip" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```